# What is the difference btw "Order" and "Degree" in terms of Tree data structure

Tags: data-structures, tree, terminology

[B-Tree Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)
they use the 'order' term in :

```
According to Knuth's definition, a B-tree of order m is a tree which satisfies the following properties:

1. Every node has at most m children.
...
```

and 'Degree' is defined in [Tree terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) as:

```
Degree – number of sub trees of a node.
```

so, are they same thing? I cannot feel any difference.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Degree` represents the lower bound on the number of children a node in the B Tree can have (except for the root). i.e the minimum number of children possible. Whereas the `Order` represents the upper bound on the number of children. ie. the maximum number possible.

**B Tree properties with respect to the Order**

[image: B Tree properties with respect to the order.]

`NOTE`: [Wikipedia also states these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Definition)

**B Tree Properties with respect to the Degree**

[B Tree Properties with respect to Degree](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture16.html)

`NOTE`: `These can also be found in the CLRS book`

Comment: To get a clear understanding on the topic, watch this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5J9M5_IMzg

Answer (score 12):

There are two popular definitions of a B-tree where:

- **Knuth Order** (**Order**) is used by Knuth's definition
- **CLRS Degree** (**Degree**) is used in the definition in *Cormen et al* in *Introduction to Algorithms* (CLRS)

Both the **Knuth order** and the **CLRS degree** measure: *min <= children <= max*, the minimum and maximum children, (*min*, *max*), each internal node in the tree is allowed to have. Both definitions agree that the *min* can't be less than *max/2*:

```
Knuth Order, k |  (min,max)  | CLRS Degree, t
---------------|-------------|---------------
     0         |      -      |        –
     1         |      –      |        –
     2         |      –      |        –
     3         |    (2,3)    |        –
     4         |    (2,4)    |      t = 2
     5         |    (3,5)    |        –
     6         |    (3,6)    |      t = 3
     7         |    (4,7)    |        –
     8         |    (4,8)    |      t = 4
     9         |    (5,9)    |        –
     10        |    (5,10)   |      t = 5
```

Key similarities / differences:

- The Knuth order k is an index counting the *maximum* number of children. A Knuth order of k means every node must have a max = k, and a min = ceil(k/2). For example, (3,6) is a B-tree of Knuth order 6.
- The CLRS degree t is an index counting the *minimum* number of children. A CLRS degree of t means every node must have a min = t and a max = 2t. For example, (3,6) is a B-tree of CLRS degree 3
- In both definitions, it is the case the min = ceil(max / 2) and max = 2 * min.
- In both definitions, it is the case that the number of keys is equal to the number of children *minus one*. So both the Knuth order and the CLRS degree are technically also counting minimum and maximum *keys* – as well as simultaneously counting the minimum and maximum *children*.
- Knuth's definition allows trees (min,max), where max an is *odd integer*, but CLRS's definition ignores them. Any tree of the form (t, 2t-1) is invalid by CLRS's definition. For example a tree with (min,max) = (5,9) is a valid via Knuth's definition but invalid via CLRS's definition.

---

Interesting asides:

- Both definitions include [2-3-4 trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933%E2%80%934_tree), which are trees with (min, max) = (2,4). It is a B-tree with Knuth order k = 4 and it's a CLRS B-tree with degree t = 2. These trees are closely related to [Red-Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).
- Only Knuth's definition includes [2-3 trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree), where (min, max) = (2,3). A 2-3 tree is a Knuth B-tree with Knuth order k = 3. It is not a valid CLRS B-tree. It's a shame that CLRS don't include this tree because they are closely related to [AA trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree).

Answer (score 11):

A B-tree is a specific type of tree which, among other things, has a maximum number of children per node. The **order** of a B-tree is that maximum. A Binary Search Tree, for example, has an order of 2.

The **degree** of a *node* is the number of children it has. So every node of a B-tree has a degree greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to the order of the B-tree.

A tree doesn't have a "degree," except in that its nodes have degrees. So a tree has a maximum degree and a minimum degree, referring to the maximum and minimum degrees of its nodes.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680041/what-is-the-degree-of-a-tree-as-in-a-tree-adt).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Order or tree

Maximum number of of children a node in that tree can have.

### Degree of a node

Number of children the node has.

### Degree of a tree

Minimum number of children that a node in the tree has.