# CLRS B-Tree property lower and upper bound on number of keys of a node can contain

Tags: algorithm, tree, b-tree

In CLRS Introduction to Algorithms : [B-Tree definition](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap19.htm) a give property states that :

> 5.There are lower and upper bounds on the number of keys a node can contain. These bounds can be expressed in terms of a fixed integer t >=
>   2 called the minimum degree of the B-tree:
>
> a. Every node other than the root must have at least t - 1 keys.
>   Every internal node other than the root thus has at least t children.
>   If the tree is nonempty, the root must have at least one key.
>
> b. Every node can contain at most 2t - 1 keys. Therefore, an internal
>   node can have at most 2t children. We say that a node is full if it
>   contains exactly 2t - 1 keys.

It says that

**t**

is the minimum degree .

My question is that **what t is counting, children node pointer or number of keys. and how property 5.b hold in that** .

I have gone through Wikipedia definition of **B-Tree** ,**2-Tree** and **2-3-4 Tree** and only found that no particular definition of **Order of tree** is given (As per **Knuth** order is equal to max number of child pointer of a node).

Comment: See [this q+a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846377)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem a bit confused by the difference between Knuth order and CLRS degree so allow me to explain. Both the **Knuth order** and the **CLRS degree** measure: *min <= children <= max*, the minimum and maximum children, (*min*, *max*), each internal node in the tree is allowed to have. Both definitions agree that the *min* can't be less than *max/2*:

```
Knuth Order, k |  (min,max)  | CLRS Degree, t
---------------|-------------|---------------
     0         |      -      |        –
     1         |      –      |        –
     2         |      –      |        –
     3         |    (2,3)    |        –
     4         |    (2,4)    |      t = 2
     5         |    (3,5)    |        –
     6         |    (3,6)    |      t = 3
     7         |    (4,7)    |        –
     8         |    (4,8)    |      t = 4
     9         |    (5,9)    |        –
     10        |    (5,10)   |      t = 5
```

Key similarities / differences:

- The Knuth order k is an index counting the *maximum* number of children. A Knuth order of k means every node must have a max = k, and a min = ceil(k/2). For example, (3,6) is a B-tree of Knuth order 6.
- The CLRS degree t is an index counting the *minimum* number of children. A CLRS degree of t means every node must have a min = t and a max = 2t. For example, (3,6) is a B-tree of CLRS degree 3
- In both definitions, it is the case the min = ceil(max / 2) and max = 2 * min.
- In both definitions, it is the case that the number of keys is equal to the number of children *minus one*. So both the Knuth order and the CLRS degree are technically also counting minimum and maximum *keys* – as well as simultaneously counting the minimum and maximum *children*.
- Knuth's definition allows trees (min,max), where max an is *odd integer*, but CLRS's definition ignores them. Any tree of the form (t, 2t-1) is invalid by CLRS's definition. For example a tree with (min,max) = (5,9) is a valid via Knuth's definition but invalid via CLRS's definition.

---

Interesting asides:

- Both definitions include [2-3-4 trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933%E2%80%934_tree), which are trees with (min, max) = (2,4). It is a B-tree with Knuth order k = 4 and it's a CLRS B-tree with degree t = 2. These trees are closely related to [Red-Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).
- Only Knuth's definition includes [2-3 trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree), where (min, max) = (2,3). A 2-3 tree is a Knuth B-tree with Knuth order k = 3. It is not a valid CLRS B-tree. It's a shame that CLRS don't include this tree because they are closely related to [AA trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree).

Answer (score 0):

I have looked up the definition in Introduction to algorigthms, 3rd edition(CLRS),t can be arbitary integer>=2,it depends on your need. We don't count it, we just set t, and make sure the properties 5 is hold. Maybe you should try to read through all the text, hope this post help you~

Comment: CLRS called this t as minimum degree . again my question is same what it is counting ?

Comment: it is definition, t is called minium degree, and we use it to define properties 5

Comment: As far as I know It is something that is called branching factor . I don't know if I am right ?

Comment: branching factor is another thing, it is the number of your child node

Comment: yes, it depend on what you need, you only need to set t to be arbitary integer>=2

Comment: Note the picture of the disk in that article. Approximately,  2t = disk_cluster_size / node_size

Comment: @codecrazer - debatable. While in-memory B-trees do exist those are weird. They are very much a disk-oriented data-structure.