# what is the meaning of order in B-tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search, b-tree

here is the question, from my tutorial PDF.

Insert the keys 10,50,30,70,90,25,40,95,45,48,60,80,35,75,43,32,78,65,55,68,99,92,96,98,94
in this order in an initially empty B-tree of order 5.

my motherlanguage is not English. so, I do not really know what's the meaning of the order 5.

I tried to use chatGPT to find the answer, but it gave me two different answers, which let me confusion.

here is the code from chatGPT.

```
          48, 68, 75, 90
     /     |     |     \
  30    60, 70   78, 80, 92, 95, 99
 /   \         /    \            \
10, 25  32, 35, 40, 43, 45   55, 60   70
                            /     \
```

I hope you can give me the exact explain and draw this B-tree. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#:~:text=According%20to%20Knuth's%20definition,unless%20it%20is%20a%20leaf.

Comment: "_I do not really know what's the meaning of the order 5._, "[What is the difference btw "Order" and "Degree" in terms of Tree data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846377/) would answer the question: "_Every node has as most 5 children_"

Comment: The term "order" is ambiguous. See [differences in termonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Differences_in_terminology). So first find out which definition you need to use. The tutorial you got should have a definition for this term.